# In Angular, how to check the route is active for a relative route?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular6

I navigate to route in component code relative to the current route like in this code snippet.

```
this.router.navigate([item.route], {relativeTo: this.route});
```

How can I check if the current route is active in HTML to apply highlight style. Currently I am using the following and it's not working for relative route.

```
<a [ngClass]="{'active': item.route ? router.isActive(item.route, true): false">
{{item.displayName}}
</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `routerLinkActive="active"` attribute?

Comment: Yes I did try and it's not working. If I use hard coded relative URL like `router.isActive('someURL\'+item.route, true)` it works.

Comment: Obviously I don't want to hard code the relative URL otherwise it's pointless to use `{relativeTo: this.route}` option in `this.router.navigate(...);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I get it to work. If there is any better solution please feel free to chime in.

```
<a [ngClass]="{'active': item.route 
? router.isActive(router.createUrlTree([item.route], {relativeTo: route}).toString(), true) 
: false">
{{item.displayName}}
</a>
```

Comment: why createUrlTree required here?? How u found out this solution??

Comment: `createUrlTree(...)` is used to get full URL relative to the current route. I used [Angular APIs](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#createurltree) to come to this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a function into your component like this:

```
isActive(): boolean {
    return router.isActive(router.createUrlTree([item.route], {relativeTo: route}).toString(), true);
  }
```

Then in your template you can write this:

```
<a [ngClass]="{'active': isActive() }">{{item.displayName}}</a>
```

Comment: What is different in your solution, other than you copy pasted my solution into the component code?